# Loading json into Neo4j Using "apoc.load.json" : Incomplete data retrieval

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to retrieve json data from mongodb collection and create it as label in neo4j. I am using mongo REST API to retrieve json from mongodb. I followed [link text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phrzW4VXjFo) by William Lyon on "Polyglot Persistence with MongoDB and Neo4j".

Problem is that i can not load all the data. Following is the format of json data.

```
> db.cves.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a37226550eb46004dea39b0"),
        "vulnerable_configuration_cpe_2_2" : [
                "cpe:/o:bsdi:bsd_os:3.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:1.0",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:1.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:1.1.5.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:1.2",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0.5",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.5",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.6",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.6.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.7",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.7.1",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.2",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.3",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.4",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.5",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.6",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.8",
                "cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:3.0",
                "cpe:/o:openbsd:openbsd:2.3",
                "cpe:/o:openbsd:openbsd:2.4"
        ],
        "impact" : {
                "integrity" : "NONE",
                "availability" : "PARTIAL",
                "confidentiality" : "NONE"
        },
        "vulnerable_configuration" : [
                "cpe:2.3:o:bsdi:bsd_os:3.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:1.0",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:1.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:1.1.5.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:1.2",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.0.5",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.5",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.6",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.6.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.7",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.1.7.1",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.2",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.3",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.4",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.5",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.6",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:2.2.8",
                "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.0",
                "cpe:2.3:o:openbsd:openbsd:2.3",
                "cpe:2.3:o:openbsd:openbsd:2.4"
        ],
        "cvss" : 5,
        "references" : [
                "http://www.openbsd.org/errata23.html#tcpfix"
        ],
        "Modified" : ISODate("2010-12-16T00:00:00Z"),
        "summary" : "ip_input.c in BSD-derived TCP/IP implementations allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (crash or hang) via crafted packets.",
        "cwe" : "CWE-20",
        "Published" : ISODate("1999-12-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "cvss-time" : ISODate("2004-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "access" : {
                "vector" : "NETWORK",
                "authentication" : "NONE",
                "complexity" : "LOW"
        },
        "id" : "CVE-1999-0001"
}
>
```

Following query works fine

```
//Load CPE collection from CVEDB of mongodb as CVE Label
CALL apoc.load.json('http://127.0.0.1:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value
UNWIND value.rows as cveData
MERGE (c:CVE{_id:cveData._id['$oid']})
ON Create set c.id=cveData.id, c.cvss = cveData.cvss
```

OUTPUT:

```
Added 1000 labels, created 1000 nodes, set 2970 properties, completed after 462 ms.
```

Question:

```
> db.cves.count();
99022
```

There are 99022 record in collection, why only 1000 nodes are created and not 99022 in my cypher query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some possible reasons why only 1000 nodes were created:

1. `MERGE` would not create a new node if a matching one already existed. So maybe you already had some matching nodes.
2. If multiple CVEs have the same `cveData._id['$oid']` value, then *at most* one of those CVEs would create a new node.

*However, I do not know why only 2970 properties were set if 1000 nodes were created. I would have expected 3000 properties to be set, given your Cypher code.*

Comment: Dear cybersam, thanks for your reply. Following is the response of some the *count* queries in mongodb . `> db.cpe.count();`  Output: `225354`,  `> db.cwe.count();` Output: `722`,  `> db.cves.count();` Output: `99167`.

Comment: And following is the response of some the count queries in **neo4j using APCO**. `CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.3:28017/cvedb/cpe/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cpeData  RETURN count(*);`  Output: `1000`, `CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.3:28017/cvedb/cwe/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cweData  RETURN count(*);`  Output: `722`, and  `CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.3:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cvesData  RETURN count(*);`  Output: `1000`

Comment: If you want, i can share with you docker-compose, cvedb and README. I couldn't understand why APOC call is not retrieving data more than 1000 records

Comment: i resolved the issue by manaully exporting the collection from mongodb by using following command `#mongoexport --db cvedb --collection cves --out cve-cvedb.json --jsonArray --pretty` and then placing it into `/import` folder

Comment: I used following cypher command ,  `WITH "file:///cve-cvedb.json" as url CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value RETURN count(*);` and the output is `99167`

Comment: Again, the number of incoming CVEs is not relevant with respect to the number of nodes that your Cypher will create. I do not see how you "resolved" your issue (if it is wanting 99167 or 99022 nodes). Did you have a problem with your original JSON data file?

Comment: Issue is resolved. `CVEDB` is updated every day by cve-search. The one i had was of May 31. And the results i sent is of today. As you can see the mongodb count for cves  i.e., `db.cves.count();` is also 99167. Thanks for your input and time

Answer (score 0):

can you provide:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('http://127.0.0.1:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value
RETURN count(*);

CALL apoc.load.json('http://127.0.0.1:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value
UNWIND value.rows as cveData
RETURN count(*);


CALL apoc.load.json('http://127.0.0.1:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value
UNWIND value.rows as cveData
RETURN count(distinct cveData._id['$oid']);
```

also

```
CALL apoc.load.json('http://127.0.0.1:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value
UNWIND value.rows as cveData
RETURN cveData._id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Dear Michael,

Thanks for your reply.  Here is the response from cypher-shell

`neo4j> CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.2:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value RETURN count(*);'  Output : `1`
`neo4j> CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.2:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cveData RETURN count(*);` Output : `1000`
`CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.2:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cveData RETURN count(distinct cveData._id['$oid']);` Output: `1000`

Comment: `CALL apoc.load.json('http://172.22.0.2:28017/cvedb/cves/') YIELD value UNWIND value.rows as cveData RETURN cveData._id LIMIT 1;` Output : `{`$oid`: "5a37226550eb46004dea39b0"}`

Comment: If you want, i can share with you docker-compose, cvedb and README. I couldn't understand why APOC call is not retrieving data more than 1000 records

Comment: I resolved the issue by manaully exporting the collection from mongodb by using following command `#mongoexport --db cvedb --collection cves --out cve-cvedb.json --jsonArray --pretty` and then placing it into `/import` folder

Comment: I used following cypher command ,  `WITH "file:///cve-cvedb.json" as url CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value RETURN count(*);` and the output is `99167`